# Передача результата работы функции в другую функцию внутри модуля NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Итак, есть вот такой код:

```js
module.exports.apiKey = () => {
  let apiKey = 'b078a7d81849e7d2b796924e54583a40';
  return apiKey;
}

module.exports.yourCity = () => {
  let yourCity = 'dnipro';
  return yourCity;
}

module.exports.yourUrl = () => {
  let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${yourCity()}&appid=${apiKey()}`;
  return url;
}
```

Эти переменные я экспортирую в другой файл где они используются другой функцией. Однако вся эта конструкция не работает, так как результат yourCity() и apiKey() равны undefined.

В основном файле я их вызываю вот так:

```js
const config = require('./config.js');
const request = require('request');
config.apiKey();
config.yourCity();
config.yourUrl();

request(url, (err, response, body) => {
  if(err){
    console.log('Upss, something wrong!:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Actual weather parameters:', body);
  }
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: покажите как вы Импортируете функции и как их вызываете

Comment: Отредактировал сообщение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 момента.

1) конечно же в переменной url у вас будет undefined. от того что выше вы просто вызвали функцию config.yourUrl(), результат ее работы никуда не сохранился. надо вот так

```
request(config.yourUrl(), (err, response, body) => {
```

ну или

```
let url = config.yourUrl();
request(url, (err, response, body) => {
```

2) если просто вызвать config.yourUrl(), то она упадет с ошибкой, т.к. в текущем контексте не определены функции yourCity и apiKey.
можно попробовать так

```
const apiKey = config.apiKey();
const yourCity = config.yourCity();
const url = config.yourUrl();
```

или переписать функцию yourUrl так чтобы она принимала параметры

```
const url = config.yourUrl(config.apiKey(), config.yourUrl());
```

Comment: Чуток по иному сделал, но в общем ход мысли уловил. Спасибо за помощь)